# How can i make 10000,1000,100 from 10 the easiest way

Tags: assembly, masm

i am looking for a solution for the question abowe.
I need to generate 100,1000 and 10000(decimal numbers).
Because the whole exercise is to caluclate:

> 10000*X+1000*Y+100*Y+10*V+1*C

I know i can do it by the mul command,but in that case 
i have to work a lot with stack.

I was thinking some kind of Shifting, but don't know how to do it 
with decimal numbers.

With binary numbers

```
mov al,2h;mov al,10b;
shl al,1
```

Preferebla is masm enviroment.Thank you for your help

Update1:
I dont want to use mul nor imul(less then 32 bit number)
I have a number as string(db) lets say 24575,i have hier the pseudo code,not finished

```
    mov cx,5
    Calc:
mov di,offset first
add di,2;so we are on the adress of "2"


;ASCI number is 2 and i want to get 20000
    mov al,10d

    ;than ASCI number is 4 and i want to get 4000

    ;than ASCI number is 5 and i want to get 500

    ;than ASCI number is 7 and i want to get 70

    ;than ASCI number is 5 and i want to get 5


inc di
    loop Calc

first:db"A$"
number :db"24575$"
```

Comment: `... but in that case i have to work a lot with stack.` - you probably mean `fmul`, `mul` works on registers. What is the value range and data type of `X`, `Y`, `V`?

Comment: Need more info. If this is about 32 bit numbers in 32 or 64 bit mode you can just `imul` them up with a constant 10, 100, etc.

Comment: Thank you Harold,it is a simply program,it is enough to use mul and the registers.Number is less then 32 bit
The shl command would be great but i can generate 10,100,1000 as binary numbers, but i need to get decimal numbers.

Comment: You can use the fact that `10=8+2`, so shift by 3 and shift by 1 and add them together. Or use `10=2*(4+1)` where you can calculate `4+1` using a `LEA` in 32 bit mode.

Comment: okey but thats not so simply to calculate 100 and 1000 and 10000

Comment: I still don't see why you need these numbers as non-constants in the first place. What's wrong with `imul edx, edx, 10000`? Just do a couple of those, add up the results..

Comment: Can i ask you that my question is fit for the request now?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To calculate `10000*X+1000*Y+100*Z+10*V+1*C` use the transformation `10*(10*(10*(10*X+Y)+Z)+V)+C`. This way you only need to multiply by 10 in every iteration. As I have written in my comment, you can avoid a `mul` by using `10=8+2`. As such your code may look something like this:

```
    mov cx, 5               ; number of digits
    mov di, offset number   ; pointer to digits
    xor ax, ax              ; zero result
next:
    mov dx, ax              ; save a copy of current result
    shl ax, 3               ; multiply by 8
    add ax, dx              ; 9
    add ax, dx              ; 10
    movzx dx, byte ptr [di] ; fetch digit
    sub dx, '0'             ; convert from ascii
    add ax, dx              ; add to sum
    inc di                  ; next digit
    loop next
```