# cannot add up ascii digits into a number 8086 assembly

Tags: assembly, x86-16, tasm

i seem to have hit a wall and cannot find any examples as to how about this. I need to convert ascii characters into a number, i.e the user types `150 + 123`, so I have to read the first number in ascii, then convert it to dec by subtracting the 0 from each digit, but here is the problem. I don't know how to actually create a number out of those digits since the user can input 1 digit or 5. Please ignore the foreign comments in the code. Thank you

```
.model small
.stack 100h

.data

  prompt1 db "Please enter an action:  ", 10, 13, "$"
  prompt2 db "Answer:  ", 10, 13, "$"
  newline db 10, 13, '$'
  buffer db 255 ; Denotes the number of maximal symbols hope
  sizeread db 0 ; It will be available on how many characters scanned
  buffer_data db 255 dup (?) ; It will be hosted on-line scanned data to fill 255 characters $

.code
start:

  mov dx, @data ; 
  mov ds, dx    ; 

print_prompt:

  mov ah, 9     
  mov dx, offset prompt1 ; Messages placed in the DX register address
  int 21h ; welcome petraukimą

  ret

input:

  mov ah, 0Ah
  mov dx, offset buffer
  int 21h

  ret

number:

  xor bx,bx
  xor ax,ax
  mov al, 10   ;set al to 0 so i can MUL
  mov cx, 5    
  loopstart:   ;start the cycle
  cmp [buffer_data+bx], ' '    ;check if I reached a space
  je space     ; jump to space (the space func will read the + or - sign later on)
  mov bx, [bx+1] ; bx++
                        ;Now i got no idea how to go about this....

space:
end start
```

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26337518/how-can-i-make-10000-1000-100-from-10-the-easiest-way/26339409).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to multiply the accumulator by 10 (assuming your input is in decimal, i.e. if hex multiply by 16):

```
    xor ax, ax   ; zero the accumulator
    mov cx, 10   ; cx = 10

input:
    movzx bx, <next input char from left to right>
    cmp bl, '\n' ; end of input
    je out
    sub bl, '0'  ; convert ascii char to numeric value
    mul cx       ; ax = ax*10, prepare for next digit (assuming result fits in 16 bits)
    add ax, bx   ; ax = ax + bx, add current digit
    jmp input

out:
```

On reaching 'out' cx has the numeric value of the input number.

Comment: There is really no need to use `CX`, you can stick with `AX` all the way. Also, there is no `mul 10` instruction, and you should be using `movzx` instead of a `xor + mov` pair. Trivial comments are not useful, you should show the higher meaning of the lines. We know `xor cx, cx` zeroes `cx` but we don't know why you zero it and what `cx` is used for.

Comment: Right. Been a while since I worked with 8086 assembly... edited.