# How do I input a number upto 3 digits in ASM

Tags: assembly, x86, dos

I want to write a progam which checks if the number is prime.

**My first problem:** How can I store an input (from 0-999) number?

```
.MODEL SMALL
.STACK 100h
.DATA

DisplayString DB 'Enter number up to 120:', 13,10,'$'

    .CODE
Begin:
    MOV AX,@DATA
    MOV DS,AX

    MOV AH,9
    MOV DX,OFFSET DisplayString
    INT 21h

    MOV ah,1h
    INT 21h ;read into AL

    ;The code to store the number here




    MOV AH,4Ch
    INT 21h
    END Begin
```

Well, if it is 0-9 it is easy, but if the numbe is like 120? how can I store it? I thought about using an array, and multiplying each element by 10, and then adding the next one.

For example, 120 will be something like: (((1*10) + 2)*10)+0

MY CODE:

```
; //READ 3 DIGITS // ;
;read first digit fo e.g. '1'
MOV ah,1h
INT 21h ;read into AL

; BL will be 10.
MUL num ; AX = AL * num
MOV BL,AL

; read second digit for e.g. '2'
MOV ah,1h
INT 21h ;read into AL

;BL will be '11' now.
ADD BL,AL

;BL will be '110' now.
MUL num ; AX = AL * num
MOV BL,AL

;read third digit
MOV ah,1h
INT 21h ;read into AL

;AL is 3, so BL will be '123'
ADD BL,AL

; // FINISH READING 3 DIGITS // ;
```

Comment: That's exactly how you do it. Of course you don't need to store the input in an array, you can do that calculation as you receive the digits.

Comment: @Jester Is there a pseudo code or a reference on the internet, like an example, of how it is done. Thanks on advance

Comment: You already showed the formula, what else do you need? Multiply by 10 and add your current digit (don't forget to adjust it for ascii offset). And yeah, there are tons of examples, I bet even here on SO.

Comment: @Jester I see, I'll try with that formula I posted and I'll get back here with the solution. Thanks!

Comment: [Here is a sample code](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26339409/547981) using an array.

Comment: @Jester I've edited my post with the code. What do you think?

Comment: You used a 8 bit register, so your code will only work up to 255, not 999 as you wanted. Also, you always process 3 digits, so the user can't enter 1 or 2. I don't know if that's a problem for you. Finally, you forgot to do the ascii conversion (I did warn you about that ;))

Comment: Actually the task given is uptill 120, so it will work with 8bit register. What do you mean the user can't enter 1 or 2? and how do I implement the ascii conversion?

Comment: You specifically said `000-999` in your question :P You implement ascii conversion by subtracting the ascii code of `0` (which is 48). I meant that  the user can't just type `10` because you read a 3rd digit anyway.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107362/discussion-between-ilan-aizelman-ws-and-jester). @Jester